# object detection api for gray scale images

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm training a tf model to recognize various objects. I have many color images i use to train the model. however, in real life my app will encounter many images taken at gray-scale due to lighting conditions or camera capabilities.is there an easy way to tell TF to train the model both on the color images and on their gray-scale version without creating a double image set:color & grayscale. i saw some options for grayscale in data augmentation capabilities but am unclear on the exact usage.